# psycopg2:OperationalError: Unknow host in Python Tkinter app

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psql

Developing a desktop application with tkinter, I had an error connecting the database to it.

I'm new to this, I was working locally but I don't know what would happen if I want to share my app with other people. The app would not have access to this database.

I tried to create a database in render.com, once created I made the connection to it through psycopg2 passing the data (hostname, port, db_name, username, and password), but it throws me the error psycopg2:OperationalError.

I know that I am doing something wrong and I have been investigating but I have not been able to find the solution to this. So, when deploying a tkinter app, what database could it use? so that everyone can use the app correctly

I would appreciate any help you can give me, thanks in advance.

Here are the connection settings, which are the same settings from the database created on render.com (I've hidden the password and host):

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname='tkinter_app',
        user='tkinter_app_user',
        password='#############',
        host='dpg-cfkimi9mbjsn9eclo3dg-a',
        port='5432',
    )
```

And here is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\luigi\Desktop\Programacion\tkinter-postgresql-desktop\src\student.py", line 134, in <module>
    display_students()
  File "c:\Users\luigi\Desktop\Programacion\tkinter-postgresql-desktop\src\student.py", line 27, in display_students
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "C:\Users\luigi\Desktop\Programacion\tkinter-postgresql-desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "dpg-cfkimi9mbjsn9eclo3dg-a" to address: Unknown host
```

When I created the database, I copied all the configurations as they were, investigating I read that the host should be the External Database URL showed in the rander database configuration, but it didn't work either and it also throws me the error: `Unknown Server error`

I also try to connect the database in pgAdmin but throws me the same error `Unknown host`

Comment: There's clearly something wrong with the host you are using, but since you're just showing `#######` we can't say much about what that might be. Is that an IP address? A hostname? Is it on the cloud or hosted locally? Can you resolve the address with `dig` / `drill` / `nslookup`?

Comment: Normally an URL is not a valid host name because it contains several parts: protocol, hostname and path. What you need maybe the hostname part in the URL.

Comment: @Chris My bad, its a hostname, i already edit it. And its on the cloud, i create a PosgreSQL database on render.com and put the settings into the connection parameters

Comment: Are you sure that `dpg-cfkimi9mbjsn9eclo3dg-a` is right? Are you sure it shouldn't have some `.`s in it? Does it not end in a TLD like `.com`, `.ca`, `.org`, etc?

Comment: @Chris This is exactly how it appears to me in render (also the other data), just like this: 

Hostname: dpg-cfkimi9mbjsn9eclo3dg-a,

Port: 5432,

Database: tkinter_app,

Username: tkinter_app_user

Comment: Is it supposed to be accessible from outside of the hosting environment? Without a fully-qualified hostname, that address does not resolve.

Comment: I think you can just pass the external URI to `.connect()` directly.